# Multiple assignment of non-tuples in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching, variable-assignment

Just to clarify, when I say multiple assigment, parallel assignment, destructuring bind I mean the following pattern matching gem

```
scala> val (x,y) = Tuple2("one",1)
x: java.lang.String = one
y: Int = 1
```

which assigns `"one"` to `x` and `1` to `y`.

I was trying to do

```
val (x,y) = "a b".split()
```

I was expecting that scala would attempt to pattern match the array with the pattern, and would throw a runtime exception if the length of the array wouldn't match the length of the pattern.

All my attempts to easily convert an `Array` to a `Tuple2` were futile.

```
scala> Tuple2(Array(1,2):_*)
<console>:7: error: wrong number of arguments for method apply: (T1,T2)(T1, T2)
in object Tuple2
       Tuple2(Array(1,2):_*)
       ^

scala> Tuple2(Array(1,2).toList:_*)
<console>:7: error: wrong number of arguments for method apply: (T1,T2)(T1, T2)
in object Tuple2
       Tuple2(Array(1,2).toList:_*)
```

Is there any neat way to use multiple assignment with arrays or lists?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

All you need to do is make your val side (left of the `=`) compatible with your initializer (right of the `=`):

```
scala> val Array(x, y, z) = "XXX,YYY,ZZZ".split(",")
x: java.lang.String = XXX
y: java.lang.String = YYY
z: java.lang.String = ZZZ
```

As you expected, a `scala.MatchError` will be thrown at runtime if the array size don't match (isn't 3, in the above example).

Comment: This works because the object `Array` includes the `unapplySeq` method, making it usable as an Exractor Pattern. `Array.unapplySeq("XXX,YYY,ZZZ".split(",")` is called, returning `Some(ArrayBuffer(XXX, YYY, ZZZ))`, which is a `Some`, and contains three elements to bind to `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: why `val Array(X, Y, Z) = "XXX,YYY,ZZZ".split(",")` doesn't work? I get `<console>:14: error: not found: value X...`

Comment: @Batato match variables must be lowercase

Answer (score 12):

Since your string can have arbitrary contents, the result cannot be guaranteed to have a 2-tuple-form by the type-system (and no conversion would make sense at all). Therefore you'll have to deal with **sequences** (like arrays) anyway.

Thankfully there are [right-ignoring sequence patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/122) which allow you to match the result values conveniently nevertheless.

```
val Seq(x, y, _ @ _*) = "a b".split(" ")
```

Comment: Quoting myself: "I was expecting that scala would attempt to pattern match the array with the pattern, and would throw a runtime exception if the length of the array wouldn't match the length of the pattern", also see Randall's solution. Anyway this is a nice one as well. So simple I wish I thought about it myself. +1.

Comment: In Scala 2.8, Array is no longer Seq, so this technique doesn't work there.

Comment: The technique certainly works, you just write "Array" instead of "Seq".  Or if you can be chill about the end of the String,

val Array(x, y) = "a b" split " " take 2

Comment: `val Array(x, y, _*) = "a b".split(" ")` also works with less syntactic clutter. I don't think that `_ @` is ever useful.

Answer (score 10):

```
scala> val Array(x, y, _*) = "a b" split " "
x: java.lang.String = a
y: java.lang.String = b
```