# `val (A) = (3)` is correct, but `val (A,B)=(2,3)` can't be compiled, why?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
val A = 3
val (A) = (3)
```

Both correct. But:

```
val (A,B) = (2,3)
```

can't be compiled:

```
scala> val (A,B) = (2,3)
<console>:7: error: not found: value A
       val (A,B) = (2,3)
            ^
<console>:7: error: not found: value B
       val (A,B) = (2,3)
              ^
```

Why?

Comment: It has something to do with `A` and `B` being identified as "stable identifiers" I think. Try: `val (a, b) = (1, 2)`, which is valid. Try this as well to see: `val (String, Int) = (1, 2)`, which has interesting messages :) I am not sure where/if this is defined, but I *think* it'd be under the `match` and "pattern matching" section in the SLS. In particular, where it talks about how matching works when it calls `unapply`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple assignment via pattern matching with Array is not working with uppercase vals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204219/multiple-assignment-via-pattern-matching-with-array-is-not-working-with-uppercas)

Comment: @pst Can we do the same with `var`? In Java we can do `int a, b, c;`. In Scala, I would like `var (a, b, c):Int`, which does not work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the second code snippet, it using pattern matching to do assessment.

It is translated to the follow code:

```
val Tuple(A, B) = Tuple2(2,3)
```

When Scala is doing pattern matching, variable starts with a upper case in the pattern is considered as an constant value (or singleton Object), so `val (a, b) = (2, 3)` works but not `val (A, B) = (2, 3)`.

BTW, your first code snippet does not using pattern matching, it's just an ordinary variable assignment.

If you using `Tuple1` explicitly, it will have same error.

```
scala> val Tuple1(Z) = Tuple1(3)
<console>:7: error: not found: value Z
       val Tuple1(Z) = Tuple1(3)
```

Here is some interesting example:

```
scala> val A = 10
A: Int = 10

scala> val B = 20
B: Int = 20

scala> val (A, x) = (10, 20)
x: Int = 20

scala> val (A, x) = (10, 30)
x: Int = 30

scala> val (A, x) = (20, 20)
scala.MatchError: (20,20) (of class scala.Tuple2$mcII$sp)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

Comment: `val A = 1` is not pattern matching? Try `val 1 = 2`

Comment: I mean ``val (A) = (3)`` is not pattern matching like ``val (A, B) = (2, 3)``, it's compiles to the same bytecode as ``val A = 3``.