# Creating a case object from the successful result of a Future

Tags: scala

I came across this snippet of code:

```
 sealed trait StatusChangeResult
 case class StatusChanged(er: ExchangeRequest) extends StatusChangeResult
 ...

 val cr: StatusChangeRequest = someChangeRequest()
 val StatusChanged(updated) = await(someFutureFunction(cr))

 updated.status mustBe cr.status
 updated.lastUpdated mustBe cr.lastUpdated
 ...
```

My question is on the line `val StatusChanged(updated) = await(someFutureFunction(cr))`. Struggling to understand:

1. How am I able to access `updated` as a `val`
2. Surely this is dangerous way of handling a `Future` (with the matchers) as it might never return?

Comment: It is a form of **pattern matching**. It says, ensure that the value at the right is an instance of `StatusChanged` and it creates a new `val` `updated` with the value of the _er_ property. This works since `await` is awaiting for the **Future** to complete and if (only if) the result of the **Future** is a **Success** with a value of the correct type. If not, then an exception is throw. It surely is not an appropriate way of handling **futures**, if it is for testing then it is not that bad _(but there are better ways)_ but on production code both the unsafe match and the await are code smell

Comment: This is called "destructuring assignment" https://stackoverflow.com/a/2382072/14955  You may have seen it with tuples `val (x,y,z) = someFunctionReturningThreeThings`, but it works with case classes (and other things) as well.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Yes I have seen val (x,y,z) ... many times so this makes a lot of sense now. Like Luis said though, it's code smell and I'll be avoiding in future.

Comment: @airudah Note that it is a code smell only because in this case it is unsafe _(as Thilo said)_. Because the original value is of the type of the **trait**, thus it may be any instance of that **trait**, if you already know which subclass it is, then you have a failed abstraction. But if you have a value that is of type **Tuple2**, then `val (x, y) = tuple` then that is safe and not a code smell.

Comment: "Surely this is dangerous way of handling a Future (with the matchers) as it might never return?" From `mustBe`, this is in a test, if the function never returns the test probably fails due to timeout.

Comment: The context of this code is apparently a test, in which case I'd chalk it up as an instance of unsafe (in the sense of likely to blow up with an exception or not terminate) code being OK in a test.  `Option.get`, nonexhaustive matches, and `asInstanceOf` are other examples of this.